# C++ read numbers from file and store in vectors

Tags: c++, file, input

I am having trouble "undoing" this method, that dumps essentially a matrix of numbers of variable size into a text file:

```
void vectorToFile(char *name, vector<vector<double>>* a){
    FILE* fp = fopen(name, "w");
    for(int i=0;i<a->size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<a->at(i).size();j++){
            fprintf(fp, "%f ", a->at(i).at(j));
        }
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I am having trouble implementing the reverse:

```
vector<vector<double>> fileToVector(char *name){ ??? }
```

I am guaranteed that the numbers in the file form a "rectangle", i.e. the sizes of inner vectors are all equal, but I don't know how to figure out the number of entries per row, and the number of columns.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Every example I found so far implements something much easier, with hardcoded size, or sizes given in first row (which I cannot afford to do unfortunately)

Comment: How do you expect the data to be organized inside the file? Can you give us an example? Meanwhile, there's an example here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677029/read-numbers-from-files-in-columns-one-column-whole-numbers-other-column-number/2677098#2677098

Comment: I thought the method illustrates. Basically as a matrix of numbers: m numbers separated by space in n rows

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm new at C++ so I'm not sure if this is a good approach or not, but I would open the file, read in the input line by line, parsing each line as I read it. Here's some example code (untested, uncompiled):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<double> > fileToVector(const char *name)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > result;
    std::ifstream input (name);
    std::string lineData;

    while(getline(input, lineData))
    {
        double d;
        std::vector<double> row;
        std::stringstream lineStream(lineData);

        while (lineStream >> d)
            row.push_back(d);

        result.push_back(row);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Great answer for a newbie, `+1` from me. The only thing I would add is that you check whether the streams actually ever reached EOF before you close them: `if( !lineStream.eof() ) throw inputError("Dammit!");` or better yet, to not to be thrown off by trailing whitespaces `if( !(lineStream >> std::ws).eof() ) throw inputError("Dammit!");`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try more C++ish approach:

```
void vectorToFile(std::vector<double> const& vec, std::string const& filename) {
    std::ofstream file(filename);
    if(file.good()) {
        file.flags(std::ios::fixed);
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(file));
    } else {
        // throw error or sth
    }
    file.close();
}
```

If you want to save as binary file, you can use ostream_binary_iterator like this one - http://bit.ly/9JAxdp:

```
void vectorToFile(std::vector<double> const& vec, std::string const& filename) {
    std::ofstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if(file.good()) {
        file.flags(std::ios::fixed);
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_binary_iterator<double>(file));
    } else {
        // throw error or sth
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you used C++ I/O instead of C I/O. I'd suggest using `ifstream` to read in the file and use `getline()` to read each line. Each line is then the numbers that are supposed to go in a `vector`. Probably the easiest way to parse the `string` would be to use `stringstream`. You can then parse each `double` out and `push_back()` it onto the `vector`, so you won't have to care about the size of the `vectors`. I'd also suggest using `std::string` instead of `char*` wherever you can (though for file names, you generally end up having to use `c_str()` on the them anyway since the file I/O stuff always seems to take `const char*` instead of `std::string`).

Answer (score 0):

You can read lines, split using the separator you have, then parse to numbers.
You can use [`getline`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/getline) to read lines as strings and you won't need to know the exact number.

Answer (score -2):

Is there any particular reason to use the vector > instead of using just double** and using new double[] to allocate the array and each sub-element? My guess is that the array can be dynamically resized at runtime, but if the array is allocated only once, using double** is bound to be much more efficient than iterating over a vector.

In any case, the solution to your problem is to dump the bounds of the array up-front in the file and read it back...

Comment: This isn't very good advice. A vector provides a lot of added benefits (takes care of memory management, provides iterators for use with many of the algorithms in `<algorithm>`, provides bounds-checking if you use `at()`, etc.). Performance should not really be a consideration at this point.

Comment: just to answer the question you stated, that is whether is there any particular reason to use vector instead of c-style array - the main reason is that OP is asking in context of C++, not C.

Comment: Iterating over a `vector` is likely to be nearly as efficient if not exactly as efficient as iterating overy dynamic arrays. Odds are that the iterators for a `vector` are pointers anyway (at least in release mode), though that's implementation-dependent. Also, using `push_back()` is going to be more efficient than continually resizing the array yourself as you add more elements to it. Regardless, the file I/O costs would drown any performance differences between iterating over a dynamic array and a `vector`. Also, using vectors is going to result in more maintainable code than using arrays.