# Reading data in

Tags: getline

these isn't any point in keeping this question around it won't help anyone.

Comment: _`isdigit(stod(line.substr(sz))) == true`_ What should this do actually??

Comment: So the idea was that I would check the first value of the line and then if It can be converted to a double I would run the function doMath(line) otherwise I would run the function tableWriter(line)

Comment: Perhaps save time and use a debugger to step through the code

Comment: [`isdigit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) takes an `int` parameter, not a `double`.

Comment: I actually did use a debugger and I figured out why it doesn't work but the main issue is that I don't really know how to structure this program in an imperative style. I am sure I am making this harder then it needs to be.

Comment: when I read the file and the loop hits the isdigit() and lines value is "3" and 3 after stod converts it, it still passes over the statement and calls the writer.

Comment: @Cody Possible duplicate of: [C++ read numbers from file and store in vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722704/c-read-numbers-from-file-and-store-in-vectors). And there are loads of other questions and answers like this.

Comment: We can't use vectors or pointers because they have not covered them in class. Apparently we need to stay within the current topics. if else for while.. strings and io and functions.

Comment: Can you use scanf? this is a pretty simple case for C style file input.

Comment: Yes I can use scanf. Although reading the api for scanf I'm not seeing how I could use that for this.

Comment: I'll post a code snippet in a minute if I can, but the point of scanf is to read formatted data.

does the number of days vary per week? this data seems rigidly formatted.

Comment: The number of employees can be between 1 and 10 and the number of weeks can be between 1 and 10. the days in a week is always 5. for example you could have 5 employees with 8 rows of data between them it would say 5 on the first line and 8 on the second and then the name of the first employee then data etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Note that all sorts of mayhem would happen if you actually tried to deploy this anywhere. This code is very unsafe because it doesn't check for failure to open the file, or for file format, or for sizes of things that are being read, or really .... anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

struct salesman
{
    char firstname[64];
    char lastname[64];
    char middleinitial[1];
    int averagecents;
    int totalcents;
};

int main ()
{
const char* inputFilename = "in.txt";
    int numberPeople = 0, weeksToHandlePerPerson = 0;
    int workweeklength = 5;
    int totalcents = 0;
    FILE * fileHandle = fopen ( inputFilename, "r" );
    fscanf ( fileHandle, "%d", &numberPeople );
    fscanf ( fileHandle, "%d", &weeksToHandlePerPerson );
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberPeople; ++i )
    {
        salesman nextsalesman;
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.firstname );
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.middleinitial ); 
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%s", nextsalesman.lastname );

        float t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
        fscanf ( fileHandle, "%f %f %f %f %f", &t1, &t2, &t3, &t4, &t5 );
        nextsalesman.totalcents = 100 * ( t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 );
        nextsalesman.averagecents = nextsalesman.totalcents / workweeklength;
        totalcents += nextsalesman.totalcents;
    std::cout << "salesman " << i << "total: $" << nextsalesman.totalcents / 100 << "." <<     nextsalesman.totalcents % 100
        << " and average $" << nextsalesman.averagecents / 100 << "." << nextsalesman.    averagecents % 100 << std::endl;
    }
    int averagecents = totalcents / ( numberPeople * weeksToHandlePerPerson );
std::cout << "total for all: " << totalcents / 100 << "." << totalcents % 100 << " and     average for all $" <<
        averagecents / 100 << "." << averagecents % 100 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Im going to read the code and learn from it. Thanks for showing me scanf lol.

Comment: It'll get you through college and programming for old school enterprise file handling. parsing files is a simple thing, but hard to do securely and quickly. That's why we have standard formats like xml and json, and parsing libraries that are super battle hardened to do this for us. 

Using scanf into those multiple floats is a scary thing by the way, it is generally recommended to do each call separately. 

If you want max speed take a look at using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use this as an example of good code layout, but there are potentially worse things out there.

In reality I should also have read those monetary values in as ints. Money should never be held as floats or doubles because floats / doubles store fractions as powers of 2 in a convoluted fashion, but can't represent simple cent values correctly.

Comment: Ok sounds good. Thanks. I just wrote the entire thing in lisp while you were writing it in c/c++. I really don't like c/c++ syntax at all. Unfortunately it's required. Good thing im am IT major. I can do scripts but not with this syntax.

Comment: that's just because you like lisp!

learn some Clojure if you want a modern parenthesis machine gun.

Comment: I've hosted a few websites with it. Clojure concurrency is quite something else.It's probably the best concurrent language at this time. Although erlang message passing is quite good too.